# getUpdate() method does not work after some hour by AggregateException

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-bot

I have some telegram bot C# applications that use "bot.telegram" nugget that have the same problem.

I get user message and commands by getUpdate() method. there is a simple example below:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        a = new Thread(new ThreadStart(GetUpdates));
        a.Start();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        bot.SendTextMessageAsync({myId}, ex.ToString());
    }
}


public void GetUpdates()
{
    try
    {
        offset = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            updates = bot.GetUpdatesAsync(offset, 100, 360000).Result;

            foreach (var update in updates)
            {
                offset = update.Id + 1;

                if (update.Message == null || update.Message.Text == null)
                    continue;

                switch (update.Message.Text)
                {
                    case "/start":
                        job1();
                        break;
                    case "Msg2":
                        job2();
                        break;
                    case "Msg3":
                        job3();
                        break;
                    default:
                        job(4)
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        bot.SendTextMessageAsync({myId}, ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

and after some hours (2-24 hours) it stops and does not get messages from user.In "catch exception" I get this error:

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
>   Telegram.Bot.Exceptions.ApiRequestException: Request timed out --->
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
>          at Telegram.Bot.TelegramBotClient.d__125`1.MoveNext()
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>          at Telegram.Bot.TelegramBotClient.<SendWebRequestAsync>d__125`1.MoveNext()
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>          at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
>          at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
>          at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
>          at mahramanehBot.Main.GetUpdates() in C:\Users\Soroush\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\mahramanehBot\mahramanehBot\Main.cs:line 45
>       ---> (Inner Exception #0) Telegram.Bot.Exceptions.ApiRequestException: Request timed out --->
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
>          at Telegram.Bot.TelegramBotClient.d__125`1.MoveNext()
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>          at Telegram.Bot.TelegramBotClient.<SendWebRequestAsync>d__125`1.MoveNext()<---

what should I do to make "getting messages and command from user" work whithout stoping?

---

I solved this problem by putting this code after "try":

```
            catch (AggregateException e)
        {
            Thread a = new Thread(GetUpdates);
            a.Start();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updates can time out and you will need to handle this - I presume the application crashes?

Catch the exception and handle the result (most likely by ignoring it). You also may need to await the result.

```
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                updates = await bot.GetUpdatesAsync(offset, 100, 360000);

                foreach (var update in updates)
                {
                    offset = update.Id + 1;

                    if (update.Message == null || update.Message.Text == null)
                    continue;

                    switch (update.Message.Text)
                    {
                        case "/start":
                            job1();
                            break;
                        case "Msg2":
                            job2();
                            break;
                        case "Msg3":
                            job3();
                            break;
                        default:
                            job(4)
                            break;
                    }
                }
           }
           catch (ApiRequestException ex)
           {
                //handle or ignore
           }
        }
```

Comment: thank you but how can I handle this exception and restart receiving updates instantly in this "catch exception"?

Comment: It should just ignore that one exception and retry again (go back to the top of the while(true) loop.  I suspect what's currently happening is your application is hitting the timeout, then crashing, thus exiting the loop.  Catching within the loop should allow it to just try again - but async exceptions can always throw a surprise or two.

Answer (score 2):

Typically `getUpdates` used for debugging. For publishing your bot, you need to use the Telegram `Webhook`. [See this](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webhooks).

> getUpdates is a pull mechanism, setWebhook is push.
>   There are some advantages of using a Webhook over getUpdates:
>
> 1. Avoids your bot having to ask for updates frequently.
> 2. Avoids the need for some kind of polling mechanism in your code.